# access item in an array in object using v-for in Vue.js

Tags: arrays, list, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to list out the name for each budget using v-for. I use vuex getter to access the budgets associated with a user but it returns each object in the array. How do I access the name of each budget in the array?

Here I am attempting to list the budget names:

```
                    <v-list-item
                    v-for="(budget, key, index) in $store.getters.getBudgets"
                    :key="index"
                >
```

Here's the getter function in vuex.js

```
        getBudgets: state => {
       return state.user.budgets;
    }
```

Here are the results I am getting:
Which is a list of objects like this,
{id:29, name:Budget1...}
{id:35, name:Budget2...}

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over array objects and show the `budget.name` within the loop.
Assuming that your budget ids are unique and not `null`, you don't need to use the index as `key` if that's the purpose.

```
<v-list-item v-for="budget in $store.getters.getBudgets" :key="budget.id">
   {{ budget.name }}
</v-list-item>
```

Comment: Thanks I literally just figured it out!